# How to do an enum mat-select option with a default from a larger array of items in Angular9?

Tags: angular, enums, angular-material, angular9

So essentially I have an Enum:

```
export enum CourseStatus {
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2
}
```

A component (partial):

```
...
CourseStatus = CourseStatus;
selected: CourseStatus = CourseStatus.Active;
courseStatuses = [CourseStatus.Active, CourseStatus.Inactive];
```

And the component view (partial)

```
<div *ngFor="let course of courses">
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            {{course.name}}   {{course.coursePublisher}}
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        {{course.courseStatus}}
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="course.courseStatus">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let status of courseStatuses" value="{{CourseStatus[status]}}">
                    {{CourseStatus[status]}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
       </mat-expansion-panel> 
</div>
```

All the code is working and running without errors to show the potential values.  However the default selection obtained from an item in the array can never seem to generate the right default value.  In my example I even populate the property of the model object to ensure it's there and correct for each item in the array of the ngFor and it's correct.  So any ideas?  I am probably missing something simple like I am casting to an enum for multiple times.  I followed a Stack Blitz for a similar issue and got most of this from here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-w-value-solved?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

So any ideas?  Should I change maybe to some array of Reactive Forms instead?  I could swear I have done something like this before but cannot locate what I did or how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know if my answer is really the most elegant way to do it but I chose to make a separate control with a view and component like so:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]='selected' placeholder="Course Status">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let status of courseStatuses" [value]="status">
          {{CourseStatus[status]}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And it's component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-status-selector',
  templateUrl: './course-status-selector.component.html'
})
export class CourseStatusSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() defaultState: CourseStatus;

  constructor() { }

  CourseStatus = CourseStatus;
  selected: CourseStatus;
  courseStatuses = [CourseStatus.Active, CourseStatus.Inactive, CourseStatus.Pending];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selected = this.defaultState;
  }
}
```

Then I merely call it in a loop like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of courses">
 <app-course-status-selector [defaultState]="c.courseStatus"></app-course-status-selector>
</div>
```

I was hoping to figure out some way to do it inline without a separate control but this seems to work.  If I don't see a better answer this fulfills what I was hoping to do.